# unittest mock cannot find attribute

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest, patch

I'm getting the following error:

> AttributeError: <class 'workflow.workflow.Task'> does not have the attribute 'extract'

This is how the codes are arranged

```
src
|_ workflow
    |_ workflow.py
|_ tests
    |_ test_extract.py
|_ data_extractor:
    |_ data_extractor.py
```

This is `workflow.py`:

```
from data_extractor.data_extractor import DataExtractor

class Task:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.extractor = DataExtractor()

    def extract_data(self):
        obj = self.extractor.extract()
```

In `test_extract.py`:

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase
from workflow.workflow import Task


class TestSomeExtract(TestCase):

    @mock.patch("workflow.workflow.Task.extract")
    def test_extract_from_snowflake(self, mock_extract):

        actual_result = Task.extract_data()
        self.assertTrue(actual_result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestCase.main()
```

I think I did it right but...

UPDATE 24/6:

In `test_extract.py`:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from workflow.workflow import DataExtractor


@mock.patch("workflow.workflow.DataExtractor")
class TestSomeExtract(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_extract_from_snowflake(self, mock_extract):

        mock_extract.return_value.extract.return_value = True

        actual_result = DataExtractor().extract(name="entities", key="11") # return a list
        self.assertTrue(actual_result)
        mock_extract.assert_called_once_with(actual_result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

In `workflow.py`:

```
from data_extractor.data_extractor import DataExtractor

class Task:

    def __init__(self, type: str, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.extractor = DataExtractor()

    def extract_data(self):

        obj = self.extractor.extract(name=self.name, key=key)
```

Not much of difference besides I added `assert_called_once_with` in the test case.

Comment: The class `Task` doesn't have an attribute of `extract`: it has the `__init__` attribute and `extract_data`. If you wanted to change this line behaviour: `obj = self.extractor.extract()` , you can go to the source to patch `"workflow.workflow.DataExtractor"`:

Comment: Updated my answer with your recommendation but i think it does not mock the `extract` function. It is still connected to the snowflake db  and query it instead of mocking it

Comment: I don't quite get how to validate if the mocking is running correctly

Comment: I wrote a code snippet based on your updated code. The main differences are the fact that you should not import `DataExtractor` from `data_extractor.data_extractor` because it is untouched by the patch mock and the full syntax of mocking the extract faction return value: `mock_extract.return_value.extract.return_value = True`.

Let me know if you need more explanations or any updates on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code example, based in your updated version:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock


@mock.patch("workflow.workflow.DataExtractor")
class TestSnowFlakeExtract(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_extract_from_snowflake(self, mock_extract):
        from workflow.workflow import DataExtractor

        mock_extract.return_value.extract.return_value = True

        actual_result = DataExtractor().extract(name="stuff", key="11")
        self.assertTrue(actual_result)
```

Some things to highlight:

1. When we mock something, we replace the attribute. So `@mock.patch("workflow.workflow.DataExtractor")` replaces the `DataExtractor` attribute inside `workflow.workflow` package with a mock object - it doesn't affect the `data_extractor.data_extractor` package, so we shouldn't use the `data_extractor.data_extractor` package directly.
2. Emphasising the previous point: `@mock.patch("workflow.workflow.DataExtractor")` is translated into these two statements:

   1. `import workflow.workflow as module_to_be_patched`
   2. `module_to_be_patched.DataExtractor = MagicMock()`
3. The mock/patch happens at the beginning of our test, so if the following import statement had been global: `from workflow.workflow import DataExtractor`, we wouldn't use the mocked version, since we first name `DataExtractor` inside our test module to be the original `data_extractor.data_extractor` object and only then execute the patch statement, which only affects the `workflow` module.
4. You need to be exact on the mock return syntax: you are calling `DataExtractor()` which is equivalent to `mock_extract.return_value` and then you chain the `.extract(name="stuff", key="11")` which is equivalent to `.extract.return_value`. Hence the full syntax should be `mock_extract.return_value.extract.return_value = True`
5. In actual testing we wouldn't be importing `DataExtractor` from `workflow.workflow`, but rather import `workflow.workflow` and call its functionality, relying on the fact that `DataExtractor` was replaced by our test.

UPDATE 24/6:

Here is an updated test:

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
from workflow.workflow import Task


@mock.patch("workflow.workflow.DataExtractor")
class TestSomeExtract(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_extract_from_snowflake(self, mock_extract):

        mock_extract.return_value.extract.return_value = True

        actual_result = Task(name="entities", key="11").extract_data()
        self.assertTrue(actual_result)
        mock_extract.assert_called_once_with()    # mock_extract is equal to DataExtractor(), which is called without parameters
```

A couple of things to notice:

1. We Test the `workflow` module, hence we call the initialization of `Task` and then call `extract_data`.
2. We only test `workflow` module, so we mock other dependencies like the `DataExtractor` of that module.
3. I had to do minor changes to `Task` class. For example, change it to get the `key` parameter from outside.

Comment: Thank you I understand. Let's say another use case where it will enter a data, with the same structure in this question, it SHOULD NOT enter the data to database. Am I right?

Comment: I'm testing out with another use case that requires me to interact with external API that will `upsert` data to client side, that have the same structure as above, the data is being updated instead of getting mocked. That's how I should validate if the mock is working...

Comment: The original `extract` method of `DataExtractor` will be mocked, so it won't be called. If this is the method that does the insert into the database, then no data would be added to the database.

Comment: Added `mock_extract.assert_called_once_with(actual_result)`, I get error `AssertionError: Expected 'DataExtractor' to be called once. Called 0 times.`, this means mock were not called

Comment: I suggest that you put the updated code (test + called modules) so it's clear what's happening.

Comment: Updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: I updated the test below to make it a proper test - i.e. check the workflow module without external dependencies like the `DataExtractor`.

Comment: Thanks but `actual_result` returns None. The test failed -.-

Comment: I changed `extract_data` to be `return self.extractor.extract(name=self.name, key=key)` instead of `obj = self.extractor.extract(name=self.name, key=key)` so I have some validation.